# I want to find out which row has edited In Ag-Grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2, ag-grid-react

I want to find out which row has edited In Ag-Grid? I want to save only those rows which are edited? so is there any method so that i can find out which row has edited?

Comment: ... not clear how you trying to update your data, pushing all to the server on each update?
what method from `grid-API` your are planning to use?

Comment: Ex - At the load time 5 rows came and i added only one row then i click on save button. So is there any method so that i can get only that row which i edited. 
@un.spike

Comment: global `save` button ? not related with `node` (row) ?

Comment: yes. correct. @un.spike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `onCellEditingStopped()` event for ag-grid.

### html

```
<ag-grid-angular
    ...
    (cellEditingStopped)="onCellEditingStopped($event)"
    ...
    ></ag-grid-angular>
```

### ts

```
onCellEditingStopped(e) {
    console.log(e.rowIndex);
}
```

Comment: It means i have to add a variable in my model may be named As 'Edited' : true by default it'll be false and on this function onCellEditingStopped i have to set it true then i can easily find all the dited rows by setting a loop on my datamodel.

Answer (score 3):

> global save button ? not related with a node (row)
>
> yes. correct

Ok, on this case you need to track as an example via `Id` what data is new. So, let's say on your data you have `unique` identifier - which will represent `Primary` key or something like that - and this key should be handled on back-end or database side.

Now, to get only 'new' nodes, you can filter `grid-data` like that:

```
   let newData = [];
   this.gridApi.forEachNode(node=>{
       if(!node.data.id)
           newData.push(node.data)
   })
```

But I'm recommending to avoid  multiple `insert` and handle each creation separately like that :

```
handleInsert():void{
    let yourDataModel = {
        ...
    }
    this.sampleApiService.sampleRequest(dataModel).subscribe(result => {
        this.gridApi.updateRowData({add:[result], addIndex:0});
    })
}
```

`result` - should return modified `dataModel` with already defined `Id`

In this case, you will be able to update `grid-data` and be sure that data is correct and already inserted into your `storage`.

> Update added example for update

Instead of `(cellEditingStopped)` event you can also use [`valueSetter`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-setters/) for tracking cell updates

```
handleUpdateValue(params: ValueSetterParams){
    // see if values are different if you have a complex object,
    // it would be more complicated to do this.
    if (params.oldValue!==params.newValue) {
        // params.colDef.field - updated cell ID
        ... handle update logic here - call API and so on ...
        // get grid to refresh the cell
        return true;
    } else {
        // no change, so no refresh needed
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It can be useful only in newly added rows not if i am updating any of row because existing rows Id will be positive.